# Запуск скрипта с функцией mail() через cron

Tags: postfix, cron, php, smtp, ubuntu

Привет!

Есть скрипт php, который делает выборку из БД и поля пуляет через функцию mail() адресатам.
Если запускать его через браузер, то все работает.
Мне необходимо сделать рассылку каждый час. Вот тут начинается проблема.

Прописал в crontab

```
 */2 * * * * (root) wget -O - -g -t 1 htt[://localnetworkdomain/test.php // пробовал с рутом и без. Раз в 2 минуты - это для тестов.
```

Ниже логи из сислога:

```
// в 13 минут логи - это запуск удаленно через браузер (случай когда все работает корректно)
    Mar  3 06:13:15 10 postfix/pickup[18599]: C9738614E8: uid=1 from=<no-reply@123.333.ru>
    Mar  3 06:13:15 10 postfix/cleanup[18603]: C9738614E8: message-id=<20150303031315.C9738614E8@mail.0600td123.33.ru>
    Mar  3 06:13:15 10 postfix/qmgr[1342]: C9738614E8: from=<no-reply@123.33.ru>, size=1302, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
    Mar  3 06:13:15 10 postfix/pickup[18599]: CC035619C3: uid=1 from=<no-reply@123.33.ru>
    Mar  3 06:13:15 10 postfix/cleanup[18603]: CC035619C3: message-id=<20150303031315.CC035619C3@mail.0600td123.33.ru>
    Mar  3 06:13:15 10 postfix/qmgr[1342]: CC035619C3: from=<no-reply@123.333.ru>, size=1319, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
    Mar  3 06:13:15 10 postfix/smtp[18608]: C9738614E8: to=<imdergac@mail.ru>, relay=mail.kuban.mail.ru[10.xx.xx.xx]:25, delay=0.04, delays=0.01/0.0$
    Mar  3 06:13:15 10 postfix/qmgr[1342]: C9738614E8: removed
    Mar  3 06:13:15 10 postfix/smtp[18609]: CC035619C3: to=<imdergac@mail.ru>, relay=mail.kuban.mail.ru[10.xx.xx.xx]:25, delay=0.03, delays=0/0.01/0$
    Mar  3 06:13:15 10 postfix/qmgr[1342]: CC035619C3: removed

// в 14 минут сработал Крон
    Mar  3 06:14:01 10 CRON[18611]: (gnoc-ts) CMD (wget -O - -g -t 1 http://localnetworkdomain/test.php)
    Mar  3 06:14:01 10 postfix/pickup[18599]: 2B31C614E8: uid=1000 from=<gnoc-ts>
    Mar  3 06:14:01 10 postfix/cleanup[18603]: 2B31C614E8: message-id=<20150303031401.2B31C614E8@mail.0600td123.333.ru>
    Mar  3 06:14:01 10 postfix/qmgr[1342]: 2B31C614E8: from=<gnoc-ts@mail.ru>, size=651, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
    Mar  3 06:14:01 10 postfix/smtp[18608]: 2B31C614E8: to=<gnoc-ts@mail.ru>, orig_to=<gnoc-ts>, relay=mail.kuban.mail.ru[10.xx.xx.xx]:25, delay=0.0$
    Mar  3 06:14:01 10 postfix/qmgr[1342]: 2B31C614E8: removed
```

В PHP файле явно указан адрес imdergac@mail.ru для отправки почты. В первом случае видно, что postfix отправляет на него. Все ок.

Когда этот же файл обрабатывает крон, то логи отличаются. Прочитать их однозначно, к сожалению, не могу, но нигде не фигурирует прописанный в файле получатель imdergac@mail.ru.
По логам он сам себе отправляет письмо, но на почту gnoc-ts@mail.ru оно не приходит так же.

В чем может быть проблема, господа?
Где копать?

Comment: @Salacoste, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Самостоятельно решил свой вопрос:
Поставил заглушку (исполняемый скрипт с функцией mail) и обращают к нему через скрипт шлюз с функцией get_content. Его запускаю через крон стандартными методами. все работает.

Comment: `htt[://` — тут, вероятно, опечатка.

Answer (score 2):

Cron по умолчанию отправляет руту вывод выполняемой задачи. Если эти письма не доходят, вы можете изменить поведение по умолчанию и записать вывод в файл:

```
*/2 * * * * (root) wget -O - -g -t 1 http://localnetworkdomain/test.php >> /var/log/testphp.log
```

Посмотрите вывод, может быть там что-то полезное.

Comment: Да ничего не пишет в файл. В сислоге все те же записи от postfix, а в файле пусто.

Comment: А wget -O - -g -t 1 http://localnetworkdomain/test.php отрабатывает нормально? У вас в строке задачи крона URL "htt[://localnetworkdomain/test.php" - в нем ошибка, в кроне запись без ошибки?

Comment: В кроне без ошибки. Если посмотреть логи, то в них идет указание, что крон начинает исполнять процедуру
Mar  3 06:14:01 10 CRON[18611]: (gnoc-ts) CMD (wget -O - -g -t 1 http://localnetworkdomain/test.php)

Потом логирует уже постфикс, как почтовый сервер
Mar  3 06:14:01 10 postfix/cleanup[18603]: 2B31C614E8: message-id=<20150303031401.2B31C614E8@mail.0600td123.333.ru>
Но по непонятной мне причине не выполняет скрипт корректно, а пытается отправить сам себе письмо.